# How can I make images multiple images responsive and center them?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a site here and I'm supposed to have their names under them and center them. A screenshot is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFznt.png), but they aren't centred and look really weird on mobile. I need it to be responsive too. What can I add to fix this?

My HTML:

```
<center>
    <h1>Meet our officers!</h1>
</center>
<center>
<div class="main">
    <figure>

        <center><img src="boysmeettheofficers/Baha Abed.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="missing"></center>
        <center><figcaption>President</figcaption></center>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="boysmeettheofficers/Adnan AL-Zoibi.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="missing">
        <figcaption>Vice President</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="boysmeettheofficers/Omar Ibrahim.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="missing">
        <figcaption>Secertary</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="boysmeettheofficers/Othman Al-Mesbah.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="missing">
        <figcaption>Historian</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="boysmeettheofficers/Salman Al-Estath.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="missing">
        <figcaption>Treasurer</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
</center>
```

My CSS:

```
.main {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: 'center' is a deprecated element and should no longer be used.

Comment: any idea on what I can do instead?

Comment: @Mohammad It looks like the image itself has white space on the right-hand-side. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFznt.png. You'll need to crop that off, otherwise even when the image is centred you'll have white space on the right. The markup of the page doesn't match the markup posted, when I checked, but display: flex is fine, see https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for some help (make ,main or parent element 100% width, height, align-items: center, justify-items: center from memory).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Solution

---

Add `justify-content: center;` to your `.main` class (or the element with `display: flex;`). This is how you can horizontally center `flex` elements.

To make it responsive, add `flex-wrap: wrap;`.

```css
.main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<center>
    <h1>Meet our officers!</h1>
</center>
<center>
    <div class="main">
        <figure>

            <center><img src="boysmeettheofficers/Baha Abed.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="missing"></center>
            <center><figcaption>President</figcaption></center>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="boysmeettheofficers/Adnan AL-Zoibi.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="missing">
            <figcaption>Vice President</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="boysmeettheofficers/Omar Ibrahim.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="missing">
            <figcaption>Secertary</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="boysmeettheofficers/Othman Al-Mesbah.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="missing">
            <figcaption>Historian</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="boysmeettheofficers/Salman Al-Estath.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="missing">
            <figcaption>Treasurer</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
</center>
```

This is what it looks like on mobile:

[image]

Comment: Thanks this centered it but it's still not responsive

Comment: @MohammadAlnesef I updated to make it responsive

Comment: oh but that still doesn't make a difference on mobile? I uploaded it here https://acaschoolgpa.000webhostapp.com/meet-our-officers-boys.html

Comment: @MohammadAlnesef you didn't add `flex-warp: wrap;` to the `.main` class

Comment: @MohammadAlnesef you need to fix your footer in mobile it takes all the screen up I had to remove it to take a photo

Comment: any idea on what I can do to fix the footer?

Comment: @MohammadAlnesef I would remove `position: fixed;` so it stops being fixed on the screen (stays at the bottom of the screen while scrolling)

Comment: @MohammadAlnesef can you please not downvote my post I know my solution 100% works

Comment: I didn't downvote anything. I'm new here. I have no idea why people keep downvoting my post

Comment: @MohammadAlnesef your post is getting downvoted because it either wasn't descriptive enough, wasn't clear or has been answered already can you upvote my post or accept my answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: I did but I cant upvote cause im new. but any tips on fixing the footer?

Comment: @MohammadAlnesef thanks, remove `position: fixed;` from `footer { .. }` that will fix it